# New Extensibility Model for VS. How to add config page for extesion?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

```
 public class Options: DialogPage
 {
    [Category("1")]
    [DisplayName("Access Key:")]
 }

[VisualStudioContribution]
[ProvideProfileAttribute(typeof(Options), "Extension Name", "General", 0, 0, true)]
internal class ExtensionEntrypoint : Extension
{}
```

It is old implementation, which does not work. And the new model I can find example. Seems `ProvideProfileAttribute/ ProvideOptionsPage` can be applied just for package `ExtensionEntrypoint: AsyncPackage`. But what is the new method to add settings page?

Comment: "Remote UI" is how VS runs extensions out-of-proc but still able to render a UI within VS's windows: https://github.com/microsoft/VSExtensibility/blob/dev/maprospe/remote-ui-docs/docs/new-extensibility-model/inside-the-sdk/remote-ui.md

Comment: yep, but I do not need to create separate window, I need to add option to existing VS settings. 

I shared example, how it was in previous version of the extension development.

Comment: As of January 2024, you cannot extend the Options window using "the new" extensibility framework - but they say they'll announce something "soon": https://github.com/microsoft/VSExtensibility/issues/245 - follow this item: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VisualStudioExtensibility-Add-options/10563563

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will find another way (Custom Window).